# Rails 3: Associations with 3 combined models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

I'm having trouble accessing a model through my associations. I have three models:

*User.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 has_one :profile
 has_many :posts
 attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

*Profile.rb*

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :posts
 attr_accessible :currentlatitude, :currentlongitude, :forename, :surname, :profpicture, :notes                      
end
```

*Post.rb*

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
 attr_accessible :title, :body, :tag_list, :blogger_id, :coverphoto, :locations_attributes
 belongs_to :user, :polymorphic => true
 has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
 has_one :profile
end
```

I want to display Profile.forename in the Posts index view next to my post title, however when I try;

```
<%= post.profile.forename %>
```

I just get the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: profiles.post_id: SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."post_id" = 56 LIMIT 1
```

I assume there is something wrong with the above associations, any idea what?

Comment: I believe that Post `has_one :profile` and Profile `has_many :posts` is wrong. But i am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Yea, I kind of played around with `:post has_many :profiles` but I got a generic error with that and it just seemed wrong. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why you do use `belongs_to :user, :polymorphic => true` ?

Comment: I'm using the blogit gem, this is actually `belongs_to :blogger, :polymorphic => true` but I changed it to simplify the question.

Comment: Just a guess, but does removing `has_many :posts` from `User` do anything since it's already referenced in Profile.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to keep your relations from both sides: `belongs_to`<=>`has_many/has_one`.
So in your case you should change:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
 belongs_to :profile
 ...
end
```

Also for that to work, you should add `profile_id` to your `posts` table.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help so far. I don't want to add profile_id to posts,as I don't think this wouldn't do what I need. 

Currently each each user has a profile and each user can write many posts. Posts has a user_id field,and profiles has a user_id field too.I need to link these two, ideally using associations. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yep, use `post.user.profile.forename`. Or, change `has_one :profile, throught: :user` inside `Post`. And in latter case use as you expected: `@post.profile.forename`.

Comment: This is perfect! I added `belongs_to :profile` used `post.user.profile.forename`. (or for those very few people in this situation and using the BlogIt gem `post.blogger.profile.forename`). Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by define association like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :profile, :through => :user
end
```

Then, you can get: `post.profile.forename`

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for this! This feels closer, however `belongs_to :user` is polymorphic so I'm getting `Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Blogit::Post#profile' which goes through the polymorphic association 'Blogit::Post#blogger'.`- Any other suggestions?